# .notRequired on yup string not working if string is empty and still throws an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I am trying to validate a string that if empty should not be validated but if there is a character then validation should start. 
I tried this but to no avail

```
iban: yup
      .string()
      .notRequired()
      .min(5, 'Minimum of 5')
      .max(34, 'Maximum of 34'),
```

If empty string as in '' it still throws a minimum of 5 error
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs on [github](https://github.com/jquense/yup/tree/1c1844293c69db5307b04764f20af3bbeaf8f265#mixednotrequired-schema), it says passing in undefined is acceptable, however the empty string does not equal undefined.

```
mixed.notRequired(): Schema
  Mark the schema as not required. Passing undefined as value will not fail validation.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a [ticket out with the makers of yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1267) to see if there is a way to do this with the built-in functionality. As a workaround, you can use a regular expression to accomplish this with the `match` function.

```
iban: yup.string().matches(/^(|.{5,34})$/, "Between 5-34 characters")
```

Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-sound-rs6il